# Округление числа от середины (.5) к меньшему

Tags: javascript

Как округлить число от середины к меньшему? Например, 7.5 округлить до 7.
При этом для 7.49 должно быть округление вниз, а для 7.51 - вверх.

Comment: Уточните, какое округление вы имеете ввиду, например 7,49 и 7,51 как должны округлиться?

Comment: Уточните, в какую сторону округлится `7.99`?

Comment: мне нужно условие середины 7,5 , а такие числа как 7,49 это округление вниз, 7,51 это вверх

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-Math.round(-x)
```

```js
for (var x=-3; x<=3; x+=.25) {
  console.log(x.toFixed(2), -Math.round(-x))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `Math.floor();`

Math.floor(7.5) возвращает 7- округляет вниз до ближайшего целого числа.

Comment: `Math.floor(7.51)` -> `7`, а в вопросе нужно чтобы было 8

Answer (score -1):

Math.floor() - округляет к меньшому целому